# Recursive replace of dynamic values

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I want replace the ID value in below text file. present it is from 1 to 200. I want it to start from 201 to 400.

test.txt

```
paraCR="0566 and 0675" ID="1" 
paraCR="0566 and 0675" ID="2" 
.
.
paraCR="0566 and 0675" ID="200"
```

I tried with the below script, but it is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=1,k=201; i<=200; i++,k++ ))
do
   find . -type f -name "test.txt" -exec sed -i'' -e 's/i/k/g' {} +
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an approach without `for`:

```
i=201
while read line
do
   echo $line | sed -s "s/ID\=\"[0-9]*\"/ID\=\"$i\"/g" >> new_file
   i=$(( $i + 1))
done < test.txt
mv new_file test.txt
```

Comment: it is printing output in the shell, how to avoid it?

Comment: Added a `>> new_file` to insert the result into a new file and then move it to `test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

With Perl:

```
 perl -pe 's/(ID=")(\d+)/sprintf("$1%d",($2+200))/e' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -pe 's/ID="([0-9]+)"/q(ID=").($1+200).q(")/e' input
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bash you can avoid external programs:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ "$line" == *ID=* ]] ; then
        id=${line##*ID=\"}
        id=$(( ${id%\"*} + 200 ))
        echo "${line%ID=*}ID=\"$id\""  >> outfile
    else
        echo "$line" >> outfile
    fi
done < infile
mv outfile infile
```